# Index on two concatenated columns SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to create an index on a concatenated column? for example:

Having a query like the following

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE name + lastname = 'hola mundo'`
```

how can I improve the search result applying indexes?

PD: my actual query is not as simple as that, but the `WHERE` part using `col1 + col2 = result` is the one that slow everything. Usually my query takes 1 second when doing something like `WHERE col1 = 'hola' and col2 = 'mundo'` but when `WHERE col1 + col2 = 'hola mundo'` it takes 5 or 6 seconds.

Comment: Something like `SELECT CONCAT(\`name\`, ' ', \`lastname\`) as fullname FROM \`table\` WHERE fullname = 'hola mundo'`?

Comment: @Xorifelse, no, i reefer in the `where` part. there is where i concatenate them using `+`

Comment: You can have that value stored in one column and create an index on that. I don't think you can create index on calculated column values.

Comment: @clinomaniac i though about that but i cant. I can not do any modification to the database(adding or deleting fields). and i cant copy it because it updates every day

Comment: you can have a 2 column index.

Comment: @isaace I am not sure if that will help when searching on concatenating the two columns.

Comment: nop. it doesnt.

Comment: I know but it will help without concatenating. You can split the string and then filter each column separately.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Does this help? https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/45842 That's the closest thing I could find that might work.

Comment: When you concatenate values like that you have created a nonSARGable query and no indexing is going to help. It has to perform that concatenation for every single row in the table. You either need to split this into two predicates or use a computed column which you can index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `+` suggests that you are using SQL Server.  If so, you can use a computed column and then an index.  However, I would first offer something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE name = 'hola' and lastname = 'mundo';
```

This can take advantage of an index on `my_table(lastname, name)` and should be quite fast.

If that doesn't exactly fit (and the space is a bit strange in a name), then:

```
alter table my_table add fullname as (name + lastname);
create index idx_my_table_fullname on my_table(fullname);
```

Then phrase the query as:

```
where fullname = 'hola mundo'
```

Comment: What im trying right now is something like the first approach you gave, just that is not that easy. In my case im working with numeric values and sometimes they include leading 0 and you know that they are omitted so i cant know for sure where is the split point. About your second approach i can not do that due to my db access level (i can only read)